# What is the most critical aspect of a CDU's output in order to obtain load discharge?

Tags: experimental-physics, electric-circuits

I am trying to better understand the exact circuitry and physics that go into a functioning CDU.

Currently, I understand that CDU’s, also known as Electronic Detonator Units (EDU’s) consist of circuitry to charge a capacitor to a high voltage, then to switch the energy in that capacitor into a low impedance load, typically an exploding bridgewire, foil, or the like, at the end of a transmission line.

What is the most critical aspect of the CDU's circuitry to obtain the necessary voltage to obtain load discharge? If the capacitor is charged to a lower voltage, can this be compensated for farther down the transmission line?

Thank you!